# Error message and incorrect font/icon sizes with new video card

Tags: graphics-card

I bought a new NVIDIA GEForce GT 710 video card and let someone replace the old one with it in my PC.  My monitor comes on but all of the font and icons in the desktop are too big.

I have checked the settings, and display and resolution seem normal. When I turn on the monitor, it displays the error

> Fail to load dlls. Please install VGA driver.

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Video cards need drivers, and your card should have come with a CD/DVD containing the appropriate software. Insert it into your CD/DVD drive and run the setup program on the disk. If you do not have an optical drive, go to http://www.geforce.com/drivers and select GeForce, GeForce 700 series, GeForce GT 710, (your OS), (your native language), Recommended/Certified, and click Start Search, download and run the first program in the results.

Comment: shouldn't there be a default/generic driver though? I've never seen this on a modern machine, ever.

Comment: @Aibobot Windows 8+ should load the appropriate "stock" driver from Microsoft Update, but not always. Windows 7 and older will not. I am making the assumption this is a Windows environment.

Comment: It is better to get the latest driver from the manufacture's website, in most cases.  I personally have had really bad luck with Windows Updates and video drivers.  I am not sure what gets loaded, but I have had several blue screens from Win Update "Video Drivers".  I am not talking about once.  I mean just about every time I try a driver update from Windows Update.  It is really frustrating.

Comment: @MusselmanLLC I know getting drivers from the manufacturer's site is better in most cases, or using reference drivers, but it is often easier for less experienced users to use the bundled disc with the card. By the wording and circumstances of the OP's post I took that into account for my answer.